# Way to disable sqlalchemy event listeners

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy 1.0.
My project has several models, some of them have event listeners, like
`event.listen(Model, 'after_update', Model._after_update)`.

In case of unit-testing I need to disable all event listeners on model/session/etc.

When particular test finished I need to enable all listeners.

Is there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: You can add a custom `@disable_for_tests` decorator that checks some global flag, and apply that decorator to all your event handlers.

Comment: Don't want to change existing code. Want to use something like `Model.clear_event_handlers()` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get all event listeners for model from [`event.registry._key_to_collection`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/bc4a96836d5bfb911da26f7e77119f3a7b356f2e/lib/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py#L26). It's a dict with keys `(id(target), identifier, id(function))`. Then remove them with [`event.remove`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/event.html#sqlalchemy.event.remove).

```
import ctypes
from sqlalchemy import event

def clear_event_listeners(model):
    keys = [k for k in event.registry._key_to_collection if k[0] == id(model)]
    for key in keys:
        target = model
        identifier = key[1]
        fn = ctypes.cast(key[2], ctypes.py_object).value  # get function by id
        event.remove(target, identifier, fn)
```